# Counting number of lines I type in vim

Tags: vim

I want to track number of lines I write everyday. I want that count to be visible on vim status line.

It should look something like `[# lines today | # lines since the beginning]`.

A log file that stores those numbers would be nice.

How to do that?

Comment: It's not clear what is meant by a "line written today". If you wrote a line yesterday, and modified it today, does it count? If you start with deleting a line you wrote yesterday, does it mean your count for today is -1?

Comment: Assume that I will never modify line once I write it.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a script that will store the number of lines in the file in a variable.  Then, invoke `vim` and as you are done, count the number of lines in the saved file.  It is simple to subtract the first variable from this number and append it to a log file with a date/time stamp.

Here is the script, you will need to modify it as per your needs:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 1 ]
then
    echo "usage: $0 filename"
    exit
fi

if [ -e $1 ]
then
    NL1=`wc -l < $1`
else
    NL1=0
fi

vim $1

NL2=`wc -l < $1`
NLINES=$((NL2-NL1))

date +"File: $1   Date: %m-%d-%Y    Number of lines added: $NLINES" >> logfile
```

Comment: Problem is being a n00b I don't know how to write such a script.

Comment: Added a simple script to the answer.  This only gives you the number of lines changed during the session.  If you want it for the day, you will need to modify it accordingly.